# How to compare array values to check correct answer

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I am working on a quiz app, so the users have MCQ's and on submitting the quiz I need to show the result.

Here is the **answers** table in the mysql db. Similarly, There is **questions** table which has the id and question columns, containing the question id and question respectively.
[image]

So I am querying the db from the model like this, this returns me an associative array:

```
$testQuery = $this->db->query("SELECT quiz_id, correct_option FROM answers");
    if ($testQuery->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $testQuery->result_array();
    }
```

Here, I'm printing the array in my controller, Which looks like this on doing the foreach:

```
$allCorrectOptions = $this->DataModel->readCorrectOptions();

    $asize = sizeof($allCorrectOptions);

    for($i = 0; $i < $asize; $i++){
        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($allCorrectOptions[$i]);
        echo "</pre>";
    }
```

The **Result** of the above snippet:

```
array(2) {
  ["quiz_id"]=>
  string(2) "13"
  ["correct_option"]=>
  string(13) "Maruti suzuki"
}
array(2) {
  ["quiz_id"]=>
  string(2) "14"
  ["correct_option"]=>
  string(6) "Kotlin"
}
array(2) {
  ["quiz_id"]=>
  string(2) "15"
  ["correct_option"]=>
  string(4) "BOSS"
}
```

In the view there are radio input tags and the name attribute contains an array (allques)  with **quiz_id** as key so when the user submits the test, I'm doing this to get the quiz_ids and selected values.

```
$nums = $this->input->post('allques');

        foreach ($nums as $key => $value) {
            echo "<br>" . $key . "==" . $value;
        }
```

The **Result** of the above snippet:

```
13==Maruti suzuki
14==MongoDB
15==Ubuntu Linux
```

So what I am thinking of doing is, getting the array result of the db query similar to the the snippet result above, so that I can compare the quiz_id and correct_option's with the user submitted values with the help of a loop like: if quiz_id.this == submitted quiz_id && correct_option.this == submitted value then correct_answers++. After that showing the result

If this approach of checking is not effective, then is there any other way to do this properly.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out, it can be done like this.

```
foreach ($allCorrectOptions as $key) {
        echo $key['quiz_id'] . "==" . $key['correct_option'] . "<br>";
    }
```